# json feed as a datasource in SSIS

Tags: c#, json, ssis

I am trying to deserialize a json feed from openweathermap.org api. After a lot of tries all, using script transformation task, I get is errors and even different ones. Based on the below classes generated by JSON, how I should write the for each statements (as class Weather and Main are part of class RootObject)?
I can get even XML data from api, instead of JSON. Would it be easier to implement the process? 
I am not asking for the answer, just a push to start.

**JSON**:

```
{  
   "coord":{  
      "lon":-122.08,
      "lat":37.39
   },
   "weather":[  
      {  
         "id":741,
         "main":"Fog",
         "description":"fog",
         "icon":"50n"
      }
   ],
   "base":"stations",
   "main":{  
      "temp":286.14,
      "pressure":1022,
      "humidity":82,
      "temp_min":285.15,
      "temp_max":287.15
   },
   "visibility":16093,
   "wind":{  
      "speed":1.11,
      "deg":13.5055
   },
   "clouds":{  
      "all":1
   },
   "dt":1479110160,
   "sys":{  
      "type":1,
      "id":397,
      "message":0.1452,
      "country":"US",
      "sunrise":1479134859,
      "sunset":1479171466
   },
   "id":5375480,
   "name":"Mountain View",
   "cod":200
}
```

**Class**:

```
public class Coord
{
    public double lon { get; set; }
    public double lat { get; set; }
}

public class Weather
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string main { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string icon { get; set; }
}

public class Main
{
    public double temp { get; set; }
    public int pressure { get; set; }
    public int humidity { get; set; }
    public double temp_min { get; set; }
    public double temp_max { get; set; }
}

public class Wind
{
    public double speed { get; set; }
    public double deg { get; set; }
}

public class Clouds
{
    public int all { get; set; }
}

public class Sys
{
    public int type { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }
    public double message { get; set; }
    public string country { get; set; }
    public int sunrise { get; set; }
    public int sunset { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public Coord coord { get; set; }
    public List<Weather> weather { get; set; }
    public string @base { get; set; }
    public Main main { get; set; }
    public int visibility { get; set; }
    public Wind wind { get; set; }
    public Clouds clouds { get; set; }
    public int dt { get; set; }
    public Sys sys { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int cod { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: make your life easer and feed your json to http://json2csharp.com/

Comment: If you are just loading the data into a database, I suggest you forget about SSIS and build a console app in C#. SSIS script tasks can be difficult to work with

Comment: Maybe this can help: http://dennysjymbo.blogspot.se/2013/05/using-json-feed-as-data-source-in-ssis.html

Comment: DaImTo: I have already generate them with json2csharp                  Nick.McDermaid: I am not familiar a lot with c#....                                      Mackan: I tried but I am getting error, that's why I tried to begin from the start